# BeautifulSoup: Delete a widget

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have a `<twitterwidget>` on a [page](https://www.wired.com/2016/08/turbulence-jetblue-flight-429-injuries/) which needs to be removed (don't need text in tweets).
  I tried

```
for script in soup(["script", "style"]):
        script.extract()
```

But it doesn't help, the text from tweets is still there.
  Also I tried deleting separate `p` with tweets:

```
for s in soup('p'):
   try:
       if s["lang"]=="en":
         s.extract()
   except:
        pass
```

But it's only a partial solution - some rubbish from `twitterwidget` still remains there..
 How would I get rid of that widget once and for all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just extract the *twitterwidget* element itself and it will remove it completely including all its descendants:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """<div>foobar</div> <twitterwidget class="twitter-tweet twitter-tweet-rendered" id="twitter-widget-0" data-tweet-id="763961058490933248" style="position: static; visibility: visible; display: block; transform: rotate(0deg); max-width: 100%; width: 500px; min-width: 220px; margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px;"></twitterwidget>"""
soup  = BeautifulSoup(html)

soup.find("twitterwidget").extract()
print(soup)
```

Output:

```
<html><body><div>foobar</div> </body></html>
```

Comment: The problem is, it can't find it. There is a `<twitterwidget>` tag on the page, but when I try to find it using `ctrl+f` or using `findAll`, it's not visible. The only way to see it is to highlight the twitter text and look at its parent...

Comment: @parsecer, it is dynamically created using js so unless you are using something that can run js to get the source, it won't be there. How are you getting the source?

Comment: As of now - primitively - using the web-browser's code viewer.

Comment: but how are you downloading it?

Comment: I don't... I use Chrome. Right click - view source - that's all I do. Anyway, I got your answer - guess I'll need to use something like Selenium to make it work

Comment: But to remove it where are you removing it from? What do you pass to bs4?

Comment: I use `urllib`: `BeautifulSoup(urllib.request.urlopen(url), "html.parser")`

Comment: Ah ok, so you are just getting the source. Well it won't be in that so you will need a plan b if there is something in the source you don't want, is it contained in the widget in what you see in the browser?

Comment: Try `soup.select_one("div.twitter-tweet")`, that seems to be wrapped by the tag

Comment: `t=soup4.find("div.twitter-tweet")` gives `NoneType`. Yes, all tweets are containtained in the parent `div` container

Comment: sorry should be `soup4.select_one("blockquote.twitter-tweet")`

Comment: Thank you for your time and help. Wouldn't have made it otherwise.